# Show/hide fields and buttons

Tags: infopath

I have a form that has multiple workflows attached to it. What I am trying to do is my first set of emails are sent to the requester, manager and project manager for review (but not edit or approve) so this will be a read only view.

Next step or I guess in this process another email is sent to the approver for their approval of the request.

Last step after approver approves or denies the request another email is sent to the head board member for final say.

What I want to do is the view for the first 3(manager,requester,PM) show no buttons on a read only view.

Alongside that I want to approver to see the approve/deny for the request.

I have added hidden fields that are updated when the submit button is clicked, but what is going wrong is I am telling infopath to do 2 conditional rules with different views at the same time.

Does anyone have any suggestions or solutions for me?

Basically I want the user to submit and at anytime go back and see a read only view. But the approver's to have all of their editing rights.

Sorry if I rambled but I have been at this all day :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are trying to accomplish correctly, you can use form rules to do this.  Basically when the user submits, it sets a value on the form to indicate the current state.  When the next person opens the form, you can use the form rules to change the view (or hide/show elements) based on that value.